# String Trie in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm pretty new to OCaml, so any feedback is appreciated. The goal is to implement a trie that efficiently stores and sorts strings.

```
module CharMap = Map.Make(Char)

(* count of members of the set that end at this node * mapping from
   next char => children *)
type trie = Node of int * trie CharMap.t

let empty = Node (0, CharMap.empty)

(* Add a string to the trie *)
let rec add (Node (count, children) : trie) = function 
  | "" -> Node (count + 1, children)
  | str -> 
    let firstChar = String.get str 0 in
    let lastChars = String.sub str 1 ((String.length str) - 1) in
    let newTrie = if CharMap.mem firstChar children
      then add (CharMap.find firstChar children) lastChars
      else add empty lastChars in
    let newChildren = CharMap.add firstChar newTrie children in   
    Node (count, newChildren)

let addAll (trie : trie) (strs : string list) : trie =
  List.fold_left (fun trieAcc str -> add trieAcc str) empty strs 

(* Get all the strings of a trie *)
let traverse (trie : trie) : string list =
  let rec helper (Node (count, children) : trie) (prevChar : char option)
      : string list =
    let string_of_char chr = 
      match chr with 
        | None -> ""
        | Some ch -> String.make 1 ch in
    let perChild = List.map (fun (chr, child) -> 
      (helper child (Some chr))) (CharMap.bindings children) in
      let fromChildren = List.flatten perChild in
    let withPrev =
      List.map (fun str -> (string_of_char prevChar) ^ str) fromChildren in
    let rec clone str count = 
      if count = 0 then [] else str::(clone str (count - 1))
    in (clone (string_of_char prevChar) count) @ withPrev in  
  helper trie None

let sort (strs: string list): string list =
  traverse (addAll empty strs)
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty new to OCaml? You're using OCaml 3.12 features and probably did a lot of functional programming before. Let's see if I can show what idioms I've seen before. I'm not an OCaml expert though, far from it.

**Empty trie** Consider using something like `Empty` to denote the empty trie. `type trie = Empty | Node of int * trie CharMap.t` This is better than your `empty` hack, and will allow you to take advantage of OCaml's pattern matching.

**string_of_char** is a nice OCaml name, but this is not *really* `string_of_char`, but `string_of_char_option`. Since it's not important, I'd tend to make it look smaller in the code.

```
let string_of_char_option = function None -> "" | Some ch -> String.make 1 ch
```

**Auxiliary function name** You don't need to use the name `helper`: `traverse` is fine. It's not ambiguous since traverse is not recursive. This applies to all functions with auxiliary functions.

**Indentation** I'm not sure I understand how you choose to put your `in`s. Also, `fromChildren` has a wrong indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Good catch on `string_of_char`. I feel like `string_of_char_opt` is a good compromise. I know it's not ambiguous, but shadowing variables from enclosing scopes (like having `traverse` within `traverse`) feels too "clever". Indentation is weird, I know. I'm trying to keep it as readable as possible with 80 chars/line.

Comment: I'm not sure about `Empty`. Adding `Empty` to type `trie` means that there are now more ways to encode emptiness, increasing complexity. Also, there's never a time that I check if some `trie = empty`, so it's not clear when I'd take advantage of the pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write the traverse function:

```
(* Get all the strings of a trie *)
let traverse (trie : trie) : string list =
  let string_of_char chr = String.make 1 chr in
  let rec traverse (Node (count, children) : trie) (prevString : string) : string list =
    let fromChildren = List.flatten (List.map (fun (chr, child) -> 
      (traverse child (prevString^(string_of_char chr)))) (CharMap.bindings children))
    in
    let rec clone count =
      if count = 0 then fromChildren
      else prevString::(clone (count - 1))
    in
    clone count
  in
  traverse trie ""
```

I think you use too much auxiliary variables, there is no need for them here.

The next step when you have a fonction like this is to use minimum space on the stack, for that you must remove the `List.flatten` function:

```
let traverse_tr trie =
  let string_of_char chr = String.make 1 chr in
  let rec traverse (Node(count, children)) prevString acc =
    let rec clone count acc =
      if count = 0 then acc
      else (clone (count-1) (prevString :: acc))
    in
    CharMap.fold (fun chr t -> traverse t (prevString^(string_of_char chr)) )
      children (clone count acc)
  in
  traverse trie "" []
```